# How can I animate size change from unknown width to 100%?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the following situation:
I'm displaying multiple `div` boxes, each with differing `width` depending on the context.
For example:

```css
.demand-2 {
    width: 29%;
}
.demand-3 {
    width: 43%;
}
```

A `div` with `demand-2` is supposed to only be `29%` of its parent `width`.

Now, there's a button that increases all the boxes to a `width` of `100%`. With the following CSS I make sure that the transition is smooth:

```css
maxLevelOff {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: maxOff;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes maxOff {
    from {
        width: 29;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however, as you can see, only for `demand-2` since I had to hard code it.

My question now, is there a way I can do this dynamically? Otherwise I'd have to create an animation for all the different `widths` and that seems tedious.
This should also go the other way. In other words, if I click the button again, all the boxes should transit from `100%` back to their original size.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your idea. why don't you add an example to clarify this ([as recommended on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use css transitions as well. When the width changes, it smoothly *transitions* to that new width. You just need to add a class of `.full-width` to each `.demand` that you want to be of 100% width.

I provided a simple demo below. If you click on the button once, the widths expand and it returns to the original width if you click it a second time.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let demand = document.querySelectorAll('.demand');
  demand.forEach(el => {
    if(el.classList.contains('full-width')) el.classList.remove('full-width')
    else el.classList.add('full-width')
  });
});
```

```css
.demand {
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in;
}

.demand-2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 29%;
}

.demand-3 {
  background: red;
  width: 49%;
}

.demand-4 {
  background: green;
  width: 69%;
}

.demand.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="demand demand-2"></div>
<div class="demand demand-3"></div>
<div class="demand demand-4"></div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have a start position in your `keyframe`

```
@keyframes maxOff {
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

For example

```css
@keyframes maxOff {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.first {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: maxOff 1s ease infinite alternate;
}

.second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  animation: maxOff 1s ease infinite alternate;
}

.third {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  animation: maxOff 1s ease infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

If you want to have backward animation, you should have 2 separate `keyframe` ones (one for forwarding, one for backwarding)

And with this solution, you need to have javascript to handle `click`

For example (you need to click on the swimlane area for the animation)

```js
function activateAnimation(self) {
   if(self.classList.contains("active")) {
      self.classList.remove("active")
      self.classList.add("deactive")
   } else {
      self.classList.add("active")
      self.classList.remove("deactive")
   }
}
```

```css
@keyframes maxOff {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes maxBack {
  from {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.third {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.third.active {
  animation: maxOff 1s ease 1 forwards;
}

.third.deactive {
  animation: maxBack 1s ease 1 alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="third" onclick="activateAnimation(this)"></div>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank you. However, how would I do it the other way? If all div are width 100%, and I click the button again, div should go back to their original width.

Comment: I updated my answer for the backward behaviour, you can check it out @Scorpia

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, looks good - thank you for updating your answer.